# В чем ошибка query_posts (сортировкой по 2 произвольным полям)?

Tags: php, wordpress

Вывожу записи с сортировкой по **2 произвольным полям**, вначале записи которые **имеют** произвольное поле, дальше идут **без** произвольного поля. Все работает если оставить сортировку только по одному произвольному полю, но если добавляешь второе, то страница просто бесконечно грузится.

**В чем может быть ошибка?**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'catalog',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'meta_query'  => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'catalog_max' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
               'key' => 'catalog_max',
               'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
            array(
              'key' => 'catalog_max',
              'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
        'ratings_average' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
               'key' => 'ratings_average',
               'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
            array(
              'key' => 'ratings_average',
              'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => array( 'catalog_max' => 'DESC', 'ratings_average' => 'DESC' ),
);

query_posts($args);
```

Comment: Мне кажется, надо заменить `'relation' => 'AND',` на `'relation' => 'OR',` У вас же записи имеют только одно поле из двух? Ну, и query_posts применять нельзя.

Comment: @KAGGDesign мне нужно что бы была постраничная навигация. Это возможно сделать без query_posts? И добавление 'OR' не помогло.

Comment: Почитайте, почему использовать query_posts() опасно https://wp-kama.ru/function/query_posts Используйте get_posts() или WP_Query(). Пагинация к этому отношения не имеет, ее можно сделать в любом случае.

Comment: @KAGGDesign на самом деле пагинация ломается чаще всего как раз из-за`query_posts`:) **Дмитрий**, слушай что говорит коллега - не используй эту опасную функцию для такого

Answer (score 1):

Совет: перестать использывать `query_posts()` навсегда, очень опасная штука для ошибок даже для опытных WP разработчиков.
В Ваших аргументах, не до конца ястно, какие посты вам нужно получить в `catalog_max`, тоесть выбирает все посты из категории(в не зависимости от существования ключа), аналогично с рейтингом. Правильный запрос, когда будет выводить посты сначало с `catalog_max`(+ проверка на существование ключа и значение не пустое, а то всякое может быть), потом посты без ключа, и сортировать по их `ratings_average`. Но чтоб не усложнять запрос и понимания логики работы, добавте ко всем нужным постам в БД ключ `ratings_average` как минимум `0`.

Систематизированый код:

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'catalog',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'meta_query' => [
            'relation' => 'OR',
            'catalog_exist' => [
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    [
                        'key' => 'catalog_max',
                        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                    ],
                    [
                        'key' => 'catalog_max',
                        'value' => '',
                        'compare' => '!='
                    ],
                    'ratings' => [
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                            [
                                'key' => 'ratings_average',
                                'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,3)',
                                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                            ],
                            [
                                'key' => 'ratings_average',
                                'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,3)',
                                'value' => '',
                                'compare' => '!='
                            ]
                    ],
                    'orderby' => 'ratings',
                    'order' => 'DESC'
            ],
            'catalog_none' => [
                  'relation' => 'AND',  
                  [
                          'key' => 'catalog_max',
                          'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                  ],
                  'ratings_none' => [
                      'relation' => 'AND',
                      [
                          'key' => 'ratings_average',
                          'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,3)',
                          'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                      ],
                      [
                          'key' => 'ratings_average',
                          'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,3)',
                          'value' => '',
                          'compare' => '!='
                      ]
                  ],
                  'orderby' => 'ratings_none',
                  'order' => 'DESC'
            ]
    ],
    'orderby' => [
            'catalog_exist',
            'catalog_none'
    ]
];
$list = new WP_Query($args);
```